# Finding specific number in prime number array

Tags: java, arrays, primes

I'm trying to find prime numbers with a specific condition in Java.

The challenge is to show all the prime numbers (under 100.000) which contain a '3' four times.
I already have a code which shows all the prime numbers under 100.000, but I can't seem to figure out how to count the ones that contain the number '3' four times.
I can however count all the prime numbers.

Can someone help me with this?

Here's the code I have, where am I going to put the numbers into strings?

```
    package Proeftentamen;

import java.util.regex.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Stefan
 */
public class Vraag_6 {

    /// priemgetallen waar 4x een 3 in voor komt???? wtf...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] lijst = new boolean[1000000]; // hoeveelheid getallen
        vularray(lijst);
        lijst = zeef(lijst);
        drukaf(lijst);
    }

    public static void vularray(boolean[] lijst) {
        for (int i = 2; i < lijst.length; i++) {
            lijst[i] = true;
        }
    }

    public static boolean[] zeef(boolean[] lijst) {
        for (int i = 2; i < lijst.length / 2; i++) {
            if (lijst[i]) {
                for (int j = 2 * i; j < lijst.length; j += i) {
                    lijst[j] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return lijst;
    }

    public static void drukaf(boolean[] lijst) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i < lijst.length; i++) {
            if (lijst[i] == true) {
                System.out.println(i + " " + lijst[i]);
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Aantal priemgetallen: " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mind to show the code?

Comment: If this is homework you should label it as such, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: how do you determine a String contains 4 threes?

Comment: You may find some useful methods here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question really sounds like a homework, so you should write down what you have come up with and what you tried so far.

There are a lot of ways to count numbers. Just to give you a clue, you can use the reminder operation (in Java -  `%`):

```
56 % 10 = 6
25 % 5  = 0
```

So, when you divide by 10 and use a reminder operation you can get the last digit of your number. Now use a loop and counter and you'll be fine.

Another option (very ugly, so don't really use it :) ) - to turn your number into a `String` and iterate (loop) over its characters.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: ...if you convert it to a 'String'... you can use a regEx to count the number of '3's as well... not as ugly as the loop...

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking at the regEx option at the moment. I never used it before so it's somewhat difficult.

Answer (score 3):

This code generate 50 permutation of numbers that has four '3' in it's digits
so check each number that is prime or not

```
public void generateNumbers() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append("3333");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
            if (j%3==0) continue;
            s.insert(i,String.valueOf(j));
            int number=Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
            System.out.println(number);
            s.delete(i,i+1);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: `if (j % 3 == 0) continue;` <- never prime ;)

Comment: Not 45, `j % 3 == 0` is true for `j = 0, 3, 6, 9`, leaving six digits for five positions each, `6 * 5 = 30` numbers to check for primality.

Comment: yes, I edited the code, removed (12 + j)%3==0 from code, because sum of numbers %3==0 is equal to j%3==0

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate across each prime number.
2. For each prime number, convert it to a string using the Integer.toString(int) static method.
3. With this string, iterate over every character (use a for loop and the non-static method String.charAt(int index)) and count the number of times that method returns '3'.  (The character '3', not the String "3").

Unless you have some other purpose for an array of prime-number Strings, don't bother to store them anywhere outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code to validate all such `prime numbers`.

```
void getPrimes(int num ,int frequency,char digit) {

    int count = 0;
    String number=Integer.toString(num);

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
        if (count < frequency) {
            if (number.charAt(i) == digit)
                count++;
        }
        if (count == frequency)
        {
            System.out.println(number);
            return ;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `primes` function from an exercise on the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/02/19/sieve-of-eratosthenes), as well as the [`digits`](http://programmingpraxis.com/standard-prelude/#digits) and [`filter`](http://programmingpraxis.com/standard-prelude/#filter) functions from the [Standard Prelude](http://programmingpraxis.com/standard-prelude), this Scheme expression finds the seven solutions:

```
(filter
  (lambda (n)
    (= (length
         (filter
           (lambda (d) (= d 3))
           (digits n)))
       4))
  (primes 100000))
```

The outer filter runs over all the primes less than 100000 and applies the test of the outer lambda to each. The inner filter computes the digits of each prime number and keeps only the 3s, then the length function counts them and the equality predicate keeps only those that have 4 3s. You can run the program and see the solution at http://codepad.org/e98fow2u.

Answer (score 0):

you only have at most five digits, four of which must be 3. So *what can you say about the remaining digit*?

It's not hard to just write out the resulting numbers by hand, and then test each one for primality. Since there are no more than 50 numbers to test, even the simplest trial division by odds will do.

But if you want to generate the numbers programmatically, just do it with 5 loops: add `10,000` to `03333` 9 times; add `1,000` to `30333` 9 times; add `100` to `33033` 9 times; etc. In C++:

```c
int results[50];
int n_res = 0;
int a[5] = {13333, 31333, 33133, 33313, 33331};
for( int i=0, d=10000; i<5; ++i, d/=10)
  for( int j=1; j<9; ++j, a[i]+=d )
    if( is_prime(a[i]) )
      results[n_res++] = a[i];
```